# Where does Joomla com_tags store the ordering data?

Tags: joomla-3.x, database, tags

I want to dump tags by order from the #__tags database table, but there is no order column in the structure, though there is ordering capability in the tags component.

I've viewed the relevant files from com_tags in reference to ordering, but I have not been able to define the logic to apply to my query statement.

```
SELECT p.alias,p.title,t.title AS tagname  
FROM #__content p,#__tags t,#__contentitem_tag_map m 
WHERE m.tag_id = t.id 
AND m.content_item_id = p.id 
AND p.catid = 27 
ORDER BY t.tagorder ASC //this column not included in table
```

I don't see any column that handles ordering. How can I get the ordering as arranged in the component's tags view page?

Comment: Looks like the Joomla's [Pizza, Bugs and Fun](https://www.pizza-bugs-fun.com/en/) event needs to pour a bit of attention into: https://docs.joomla.org/Tables

Comment: I do not endorse the use of old-school comma-joins.  (Although there is no loss of performance or integrity in your style, there is [a fringe case for others to be aware of](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html#:~:text=JOIN%20has%20higher%20precedence,those%20operands%20are.).) Your query will be easier to read with the verbose `JOIN ... ON` syntax.  What kind of special ordering do you want?  Are you not happy to use `usort()` in php?

Comment: @mickmackusa ```usort()``` would be fine if I had given values to work from. None of the columns of the ```#__tags``` table are applicable since they do not represent the sorted order as displayed in the HTML view in the admin table. I need to pass the sorted output to a file in the admin template, and able to have that data rearrange dynamically when I change the tags' sort order. The file is not for distribution, so the "old-school comma-joins" will suffice. If you prefer it rewritten for this forum, I'll do so.

Comment: No, no, I don't need you to rewrite anything.  I am just making an observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use column `lft` to order by the tag component's ordering.

The tags use nested ordering like the menu table - for a post that discusses nested ordering see [Ordering Joomla menus in code](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/23743/ordering-joomla-menus-in-code)